# Numeric to datetime conversion in SQL Server 2016 error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

This is for SQL Server 2016.

Column

```
MyDate
---------
20200915
20201007
```

Unfortunately the data type is `numeric(8,0)`

I am trying to get date as

```
2020-09-15 00:00:00
2020-10-07 00:00:00
```

Code:

```
convert(varchar, MyDate, 120)
```

Please suggest

Thanks

Comment: I suppose the real question is why is your *column* a `numeric(8,0)` and not a `date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write this as:

```
convert(date, convert(varchar(8), mydate))
```

SQL Server does not allow converting an integer to a date directly, so we need an intermediate casting to a string. If you want a date an time, use `datetime` instead of `date`.

If there is a chance that some of your numeric dates might be invalid, you can use `try_convert()` instead of `convert()`.

Another option is arithmetics and `datefromparts()` (I doubt that is is more efficient):

```
datefromparts(mydate / 10000, (mydate % 10000) / 100, mydate % 100)
```